# Can I do inorder traversal of a binary tree without recursion and stack?

Tags: tree, tree-traversal

Can anyone give me a solution for traversing a binary tree in inorder without recursion and without using a stack?

Comment: if you'll be able to do it, it won't be binary tree

Comment: Isn't this a homework?

Does a counter count as stack in your case?

Comment: @Jim Lewis I didn't know this, thanks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second edit:  I think this is right.  Requires node.isRoot, node.isLeftChild, and node.parent, in addition to the usual node.left_child and node.right_child.

```
state = "from_parent"
current_node = root
while (!done)
  switch (state)
    case "from_parent":
      if current_node.left_child.exists
        current_node = current_node.left_child
        state = "from_parent"
      else
        state = "return_from_left_child"
    case "return_from_left_child"
      if current_node.right_child.exists
        current_node = current_node.right_child
        state = "from_parent"
      else
        state = "return_from_right_child"
    case "return_from_right_child"
      if current_node.isRoot
        done = true
      else
        if current_node.isLeftChild
         state = "return_from_left_child"
        else
         state = "return_from_right_child"
        current_node = current_node.parent
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is going to have problems with trees of depth > 2.

Comment: You beat me to it. But note that this works only if the field node.parent exists, that is if the node knows its parent. This is permitted, but not required, by the definition of a binary tree.

Comment: If you have node.parent, you don't need node.isRoot. Also, I think you can do without node.isLeftChild.

Comment: @mbeckish incredible especially if this came right from the top of your head

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Double threaded tree

If your tree nodes have parent references/pointers, then keep track of which you node you came from during the traversal, so you can decide where to go next.

In Python:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.parent = None
        if self.left:
            self.left.parent = self
        if self.right:
            self.right.parent = self

    def inorder(self):
        cur = self
        pre = None
        nex = None
        while cur:
            if cur.right and pre == cur.right:
                nex = cur.parent
            elif not cur.left or pre == cur.left:
                yield cur.value  # visit!
                nex = cur.right or cur.parent
            else:
                nex = cur.left
            pre = cur
            cur = nex

root = Node(1,
            Node(2, Node(4), Node(5)),
            Node(3)
        )

print([value for value in root.inorder()])  # [4, 2, 5, 1, 3]
```

### 2. Single threaded tree

If your tree nodes do not have parent references/pointers, then you can do a so-called Morris traversal, which temporarily mutates the tree, making the `right` property -- of a node that has no right child -- temporarily point to its inorder successor node:

In Python:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def inorder(self):
        cur = self
        while cur:
            if cur.left:
                pre = cur.left
                while pre.right:
                    if pre.right is cur:
                        # We detect our mutation. So we finished
                        # the left subtree traversal.
                        pre.right = None
                        break
                    pre = pre.right
                else:  # prev.right is None
                    # Mutate this node, so it links to curr
                    pre.right = cur
                    cur = cur.left
                    continue
            yield cur.value
            cur = cur.right

root = Node(1,
            Node(2, Node(4), Node(5)),
            Node(3)
        )

print([value for value in root.inorder()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since traversing a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) requires some kind of state (nodes to return after visiting successors) which could be provided by stack implied by recursion (or explicit by an array).

The answer is no, you can't. (according to the classic definition)

The closest thing to a binary tree traversal in an iterative way is probably using a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

EDIT:
Or as already shown  a [threaded binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree) ,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In order to do this, you would require a parent pointer in order to ascend the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Start with tree_first(), continue with tree_next() until get NULL.
Full code: https://github.com/virtan/tree_closest

```
struct node {
    int value;
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *parent;
};

node *tree_first(node *root) {
    while(root && root->left)
        root = root->left;
    return root;
}

node *tree_next(node *p) {
    if(p->right)
        return tree_first(p->right);
    while(p->parent) {
        if(!p->parent->right || p->parent->right != p)
            return p->parent;
        else p = p->parent;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The routine used in the combinator cruncher [Combo](https://github.com/RockBrentwood/Combo) is non-recursive, for binary trees, and uses no stacks and no "up" pointer - just the two branch pointers.

This is pseudo-code cast in the mold of C.

The current state is (P,E,N). An iteration starts with (P,E,N) ← (NULL,Root,-), where the "N" does not need to be initialized. The ending condition is where "E == NULL". The iterator is called "DOWN(P,E,N)" and has the form (P,E,N) ← (E,N,-). On leaf nodes, you have "FLIP(P,E,N)", which is (P,E,N) ← (N,E,P). It may also be used on non-leaf nodes depending on the condition of the traversal. A leaf node is normally, otherwise, handled with SPIN(P,E,N), which is (P,E,N) ← (-, (Head: Tail(E), Tail: P), Head(E)). This returns a visit count for E and bumps it up. In some cases, if backing out, you'll do UNSPIN(P,E,N), which is (P,E,N) ← (Head(E), (Head: Tail(E), Tail: N), -), which also returns the visit count and bumps it up. In both cases, it is bumped up modulo 3 for binary trees.

In a concurrent environment, a thread has to wait for a node's visit count to cycle through, by whatever other thread is using it, before using SPIN or UNSPIN. So, that has to be managed properly, too.

In the implementation of "Combo", the constructor uses sub-tree hashing. So, no subtree is ever duplicated - not even leaf nodes. It's ideally suited for scaling up to rational infinite trees, that would be implemented by cyclic graphs. That was the intent. So, theoretically (if you scale up the design right) you could even use this to work with **infinite** trees - provided they're rational.

Answer (score -1):

As someone here already stated, it is possible, but not without the parent pointer. The parent pointer basically allows you to traverse "the path" if you want, and therefore print-out the nodes.
But why does recursion works without parent pointer? Well if you understand recursion it goes something like this(imagine the recursion stack):

```
  recursion //going into
   recursion
    recursion
     recursion 
     recursion //going back up
    recursion
   recursion
  recursion
```

So when the recursion ends you then have printed the chosen side of the binary tree in reversed order.

Comment: The OP does explicitly ask for something **not** involving **recursion**.